# Como configuro o dropzone JS para receber uma imagem apenas teclando o CTRL+ V,de modo que aceite texto e imagens juntos?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estava observando o outlook e o campo de edição do e-mail recebe imagens via CTRL + V, pesquisando encontrei que isso seria um componente dropzone. Gostaria de saber como configurar.

Abaixo o exemplo do outlook.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma olhada na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)  ou use uma [lib](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Comment: O outlook utiliza editor WYSIWYG

Comment: irei estudar @MarcosBrinner , você aconselha algum em especifico?

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.onpaste = function(event){
      var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
      for (index in items) {
        var item = items[index];
        if (item.kind === 'file') {
          // adds the file to your dropzone instance
          myDropzone.addFile(item.getAsFile())
        }
      }
    }
```

Coloca o código acima dentro da função init